# I cant delete rows created dynamically using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I cant delete rows created by ajax and jquery. I have a first page with add-0customer.php ans ajax page with ajax_add_country.php. I want to delete rows with id `one<?php echo $cnt ?>`. These rows are created dynamically using jquery ajax.

ajax_add_country.php contain

```
 $cnt=$_POST['cnt'];
<tr id="one<?php echo $cnt ?>">
  <td><input type="text" name="country2[]" 
  value="<?php echo $coun_real_name;?>"     class="shorttext"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="country[]"
  value="<?php echo $country;?>"  class="shorttext"/>
  </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="currency[]"
 value="<?php echo $currency;?>" class="shorttext" /></td>
 <td><textarea name="bank[]" cols="" rows=""><?php echo $bank;?></textarea></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="exchange_rate[]" 
  value="<?php echo $exchange_rate;?>"  class="shorttext"/></td>
 <td><p onclick="deletes(one<?php echo $cnt ?>)"> Delete  </p></td>
```

My delete function in add_customer.php

```
function deletes(id)
 {
    $('#id').remove();
  }
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate passed id with '#' like below

```
function deletes(id)
{
    $('#'+id).remove();
}
```

**Note** - make sure that all `id`s should be unique throughout the html.

Comment: The second solution does not make any sense. And we don't need to worry about dynamical things while binding events with inline handler.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I was not sure about that so just added if first one not work. But as you are sure that we don't need second solution then I will remove it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
$('#id').remove();
```

Your are searching an element that has ( ID === "#id" ) means as string.

As already suggested, use:

```
$('#' + id).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('table tr#one').remove();

or

$("#test tr:eq('one')").remove();

or

$('#one').remove();
```